# Anyway to get rid of an image in blender?

Tags: image

An image is preventing me from packing the blend file. The image is not used (and exists where it is supposed to be on disk so I don't know why I'm getting the error). Users are not listed next to the images so I can't get rid of it that way. Is there any way to remove the image from Blender?

Thanks,
Rusty

Comment: If it has no users, you could try closing blender and re-opening. Orphaned data should be discarded.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete any object in blend file if you open this section of the outliner
[image]

There you will find all inside of the blend file and then delete it

[image: Content of the file]

Comment: This is a great answer. It really changed my game when I first learned about this. Texture paint slots, for example, seem to have absolutely no way to be deleted except by this method.